# R For loop slows down gradually

Tags: r, for-loop, twitter

I have a dataset of tweets, from where I extract the list of mentioned people, then for each mention I create a separate row in a different data frame. If original data looks like this:

User  | Tweet
A        | @B @C @D Hey what's up guys

I make it look like:

User  | Mentions
A      |  B
A      |  C
A      |  D

The problem is, I use for loop for this which gets slower over time. The first 10000 instances happen very fast, then it goes through 1000 instances per second, by the time it reaches 200K, it does 25 instance per second. Here's my code. What can I do to improve the performance? There are over 5 million tweets and this is too slow.

```
#create edge df
networks <- data.frame(user = character(), 
                   mentions=character(), 
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

#get all mentioned
mentionlist <- str_extract_all(tweets$tweet, "(?<=^|\\s)@[^\\s]+")


#start collecting edges
a <- 0
b <- 0 

for(i in mentionlist){
  a <- a+1
  for(j in i){
    b <- b+1
    networks[b,1] <- tweets[a,9]
    networks[b,2] <- j
    print(b) #to keep track of it
    #print(paste0(j, "   ", tweets[a,8], "   ",networks[b,1] ))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save all the mentions in a list and use `unnest` to get them in different rows. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

tweets %>%
  mutate(Mentions = stringr::str_extract_all(Tweet, "(?<=^|\\s)@[^\\s]+")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(Mentions) -> result

result
```